# DevDemon Subscriptions: Cannot view details of transaction in Logs

Tags: devdemon-subscriptions

Using DevDemon Subscriptions v 1.6.
Anytime that I go to "logs" and click on the ID of an entry to see if there are more details I get a screen that says "The requested module page could not be found.".
Are there more details to be found?  This happens on every log entry.
[image]